# Programatically add custom rule in Stardog

Tags: java, command-line-interface, sparql, triples, stardog

I'm able to add custom rules to a named graph in Stardog with the following CLI command:

```
stardog data add db_name -g "http://graph_name"/path/to/rules/test.ttl
```

Is there a possibility to do this via the Java API, for instance with the `AdminConnection` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding data to the database would be done using the `Connection` class. You can specify a named graph for the file you are adding as follows:

```
conn.begin();
conn.add().io().context(graphURI).file(new File("/path/to/rules/test.ttl"));
conn.commit();
```

See the [connection](http://docs.stardog.com/java/snarl/com/complexible/stardog/api/Connection.html) and [adder](http://docs.stardog.com/java/snarl/com/complexible/stardog/api/Adder.html) classes for more details.

Comment: Additionally, in Stardog 3, `ExpressionFactory#rule` can be used to create an `Expression` from a Stardog Rule (as a string).  An `Expression` can be turned into a graph via the `graph` method, we can then be passed to `Adder` to insert it into the database.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions! I will try the second solution as well when Stardog 3 is released